# PIC32mx UART to Bluetooth RN4020

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, bluetooth, microchip

I am trying to establish an UART comunication between [PIC32MX110F016](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001168H.pdf) and a [RN4020](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002279B.pdf) Bluetooth Module.

I am new on PIC32mx but I think I am doing enough code/configuration for them to comunication but unfortunately they aren't and I really don't know why. I don't know the reason why so I get back to you guys.
This is the code I have made. Does someone has some tip?

```
#pragma config   FNOSC       = FRCPLL
#pragma config   FPLLIDIV    = DIV_2
#pragma config   FPLLMUL     = MUL_20
#pragma config   FPLLODIV    = DIV_2
#pragma config   FPBDIV      = DIV_1
#pragma config   ICESEL      = ICS_PGx2 
#pragma config   WDTPS       = PS16384

#define GetSystemClock()       (40000000ul)
#define GetPeripheralClock()    (GetSystemClock())
#define CORE_TICK_RATE (GetSystemClock() / 2 / 1000) 

#define BaudRate   38400 

char Message[] = "Hello!";

void __ISR(_UART_1_VECTOR, ipl2)UART1_RX_INT(void){
if(INTGetFlag(INT_SOURCE_UART_RX(    
       INTClearFlag(INT_SOURCE_UART_RX(UART1)); 
}   
if(INTGetFlag(INT_SOURCE_UART_TX(UART1))){        
 INTClearFlag(INT_SOURCE_UART_TX(UART1));    
}
}  

void Serial_print(char *buffer)
{ 
while(*buffer != (char)0) 
{
  while(!UARTTransmitterIsReady(UART1)); 
  UARTSendDataByte(UART1, *buffer++); 
}
while(!UARTTransmissionHasCompleted(UART1)); 
UARTSendDataByte(UART1, '\r'); 
UARTSendDataByte(UART1, '\n'); 
} 

void uartconfig(void){
PPSUnLock;                        // Allow PIN Mapping 
  PPSOutput(1, RPA0, U1TX);     // MAP Tx to RA0 set to digital out
  PPSInput (3, U1RX, RPA2);     // MAP Rx to RA2 set to digital in
PPSLock;                         // Prevent Accidental Mapping

#define UART1TX TRISAbits.TRISA0
#define UART1RX TRISAbits.TRISA2

UART1TX = 0;//output
UART1RX = 1;//input     

UARTConfigure(UART1, UART_ENABLE_PINS_TX_RX_ONLY); 
UARTSetLineControl(UART1, UART_DATA_SIZE_8_BITS | UART_PARITY_NONE |UART_STOP_BITS_1); 
UARTSetDataRate(UART1, GetPeripheralClock(), BaudRate); 
UARTEnable(UART1, UART_ENABLE_FLAGS(UART_PERIPHERAL | UART_RX | UART_TX));  
UARTSetFifoMode(UART1, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);          
INTEnable(INT_SOURCE_UART_RX(UART1), INT_ENABLED);   
INTSetVectorPriority(INT_VECTOR_UART(UART1), INT_PRIORITY_LEVEL_2);   
INTSetVectorSubPriority(INT_VECTOR_UART(UART1), INT_SUB_PRIORITY_LEVEL_0); 
}


int32_t main(void) {
__asm__("EI"); 
SYSTEMConfig(GetSystemClock(), SYS_CFG_WAIT_STATES | SYS_CFG_PCACHE);
INTConfigureSystem(INT_SYSTEM_CONFIG_MULT_VECTOR); //configure multi vector
INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt(); //enable interrupts
uartconfig();
WDTCONbits.WDTCLR = 1; // feed the watchdog
WDTCONbits.ON = 1; // enable the watchdog

uartconfig();

Serial_print(Message);
while(1);
}
```

For better understanding you can take a look at my schematic:

[image: RN4020 Bluetooth Schematic]

[image: Pic]

Comment: You asked for a tip, and here it is: Don't try making this work by talking to a device that you don't know is working either.  Use a trusted device or maybe have the UART talk to itself.

Comment: My Pic is working perfectly and the Bluetooth is also well powered. How can I know if Bluetooth is working perfectly without trying to communicate with it?

Comment: Am I asking something stupid to be downvoted? Is there any problem of not using Pin 8 (CMD/MLDP)?

Comment: How do you know its not working? How are you viewing the results? Have you tried connecting TX/RX with your PC to see if you can receive the message with Putty or some serial terminal?

Comment: @TisteAndii I know the bluetooth is well powered because I can see it in my phone but I can not do what you suggest because the serial port is through the bluetooth.
So there's no way to see the messages directly in my pc without the Bluetooth working.

Comment: What I mean is, when you send a message to the BT module, how do you view what was sent? How do you know the message was received or not? Does the module have a display? Also, you CAN test that UART is working by connecting TX RX and GND to a USB-TTL cable and connecting this to your PC. If the PIC is actually sending the message, you can view the message using Putty. To make the PIC send the message continuously, place the Serial_print(message) in an infinite loop

Comment: well, I know I can do that but unfortunately I have no way to do it in this design. I have no uart-usb converter here.
I just know the UART-TX is at 3.3V and the RX as well. I measure it by putting the multimeter there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to work fine (apart from a bit missing from the interrupt routine, which I assume is just a copy/paste error because it won't compile as-is).

However it only sends the serial message once on startup, then waits forever. The PIC starts sending data about 1ms after coming out of reset, so if both the Bluetooth and PIC are powered up at the same time the Bluetooth module might not be ready in time to receive the message.

For debugging I would send the message repeatedly in the while() loop, with a delay of about 1 second before each transmission. To prove that the PIC is sending data you could wire an LED (and series resistor) from the TX pin to Vcc. The LED should flash briefly in time with the message. If this works but the message still doesn't get through then check the wiring and configuration of your Bluetooth module.